# Semantic UI react size prop on image element

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

I have a `HomepageHeading` that I'm rendering at the top of the pages in my app. I'm using a custom image inside a `<Header>` and trying to adjust the size so it's fairly large.

[`<Image>`](https://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/image/) takes a size prop, so I set it to `massive` as seen below. It sort of has the opposite effect and doesn't make the image much bigger than If I set it to `tiny`. I have provided a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/n1wpk96vx0) for visual.

Is this a bug or am I setting the prop incorrectly? Maybe `<Image>` wrapped inside a `<Header>` behaves differently?

```
const HomepageHeading = ({ mobile }) => (
  <Container text>
    <Header
      as="h1"
      inverted
      style={{
        fontSize: mobile ? "2em" : "4em",
        fontWeight: "normal",
        marginBottom: 0,
        marginTop: mobile ? "1.5em" : "3em"
      }}
    >
      <Image
        size="massive"
        src="https://react.semantic-ui.com/images/avatar/large/patrick.png"
      />
    </Header>

    <Header
      as="h2"
      content="Something"
      inverted
      style={{
        fontSize: mobile ? "1.5em" : "1.7em",
        fontWeight: "normal",
        marginTop: mobile ? "0.5em" : "1.5em"
      }}
    />
  </Container>
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right the Header component contains styling that overrides the styles being applied by the Image size prop.

I'm seeing that the Header is adding a width of `2.5em` overriding the `960px` that the massive size prop is trying to set.

To make the image the size that you want, you're going to have to apply your own styles to it.

Try adding the following to Image:

`style={{width: '960px', height: 'auto'}}`

---

Comment: Interesting, thanks for pointing this out. Not sure if I missed it in the docs, or it's just normal for a wrapped component styling to take precedent.

Comment: You didn't miss it in the docs. It's normal to come across these issues with any UI library because css inheritance is tricky and sometimes there is no way around it when creating these types of components.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue after updating my semantic-ui-react dependency. An `<Image>` inside a `<Header>` would always look as if it had `size='tiny'`. I traced this behavior down to this rule

```
.ui.header>img {
  width: 2.5em 
}
```

Solution

I simply wanted the size attribute of my `<Image>` to work as usual, so I added an override in one of my personal stylesheets.

```
/* Semantic UI override */
.ui.small.image {
    width: 150px !important;
}
```

The only addition here is the `!important` modifier at the end. Now `size='small'` works on my `<Image>` like normal. Voila!